# changing the socket RemoteEndPoint

Tags: c#, sockets

I have a socket that is already connected to a RemoteEndPoint, and I want to change the port of that RemoteEndPoint, when I try :

```
//4511 is the new port
sHandler.Connect(IPAddress.Parse("172.10.10.17"), 4511);
```

It says that the sHandler is already connected to ...

How Can I change the socket RemoteEndPoint ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't change a port when you are already connected. If you want to switch to another port you need to close the socket first and then reconnect.

But maybe there are more to it than this?
And that you named your socket "socketListener" sounds a bit like its a listening socket? If I am missing something please let us know more about the situation.